# Is there a groovier alternative to object construction via "with"-function

Tags: java, groovy

We use Groovy only for our tests, that means that all our domain classes and so forth are still normal Java classes. To easily create test data we currently use the following technique:

Example Java Class

```
public class Domain {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private Domain parent;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Domain getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Domain parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Example Object construction in Groovy

```
Domain test = new Domain().with {
    name = "Test Object"
    id = 42

    delegate
}
```

Nested Construction

```
Domain test = new Domain().with {
    name = "Test Object"
    id = 42
    parent = new Domain().with {
        name = "Parent"
        id = 47

        delegate
    }

    delegate
}
```

As you can see the `Domain` object is created and then configured via the `with` function of Groovy. The ugly thing here is the `delegate` at the end which returns the actual object again. If we would not use it here the result would be `42` instead of the configured object.

Is there a Groovier way to do this with the standard Groovy functions, so no categories, mixins, or custom helper functions.

---

EDIT:
Added nested object construction example.

EDIT 2:
Both answers work do work:

```
import spock.lang.Specification


class StackOverflow extends Specification {

    def "Answer Ian Roberts" () {
        when:
        Domain test = new Domain(
                name: "Test object",
                id: 42,
                parent: new Domain(name: "Parent", id: 47))

        then:
        test.name == "Test object"
        test.id == 42
        test.parent.name == "Parent"
        test.parent.id == 47
    }

    def "Answer tim_yates"() {
        when:
        Domain test = [
            name: "Test object",
            id: 42,
            parent: [name:"Parent", id:47]
        ]

        then:
        test.name == "Test object"
        test.id == 42
        test.parent.name == "Parent"
        test.parent.id == 47
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the "named parameters" map constructor syntax with any Java class provided it has a no-argument constructor:

```
Domain test = new Domain(
    name:"Test object",
    id:42,
    parent:new Domain(name:"Parent", id:47))
```

Behind the scenes, Groovy will call the no-arg constructor followed by the Java Bean property setters, and then return the resulting object.

Comment: Both answers do work, I've selected this one since its code will be more clear for the nested scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it works with POJOs, but can you try:

```
Domain test = [ name:'Test Object', id: 42 ]
```